# automatically delete conflict file on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, synchronization

I use Google Drive to hold data (which I sometime share with others), and end up with a "conflict" file.

When this happens, synchronisation stops working altogether. However, if I remove the conflict file manually, sync starts working again.

Is there a method for removing conflict files automatcally on Google Drive?

I can perhaps write a batch file or a short app to do it, but don't think it would be the best way?.

Comment: how would you know which one to delete? seems risky and i think the only way is to do it with code. like a time driven trigger from apps script.

Comment: Could you give some more details on what you define as a conflict file, or if you get any kind of error message or warning?